# getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token . in mongo shell while creating embedded index on a collection

Tags: mongodb

```
db.dashboard_project.createIndex({
  projectName:"text",
  projectDescription:"text",
  skillList.skillName:"text"
})
```

where skillList has a field named skillName

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the field of embedded document in double quotes:

```
db.dashboard_project.createIndex({
  projectName:"text",
  projectDescription:"text",
  "skillList.skillName":"text"
})
```